# Gnuplot: Tilde Symbol in pngcairo image

Tags: gnuplot

I use Gnuplot with pngcairo terminal and my question ison can I put the tilde symbol on a letter?

I know that in latex the command is `\tilde{f}`. 
I've tried with `f{\Symbol 304}` or `f\\~`.

How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Check `help enhanced text`.

With this:

```
### tilde over character
set label 1 "~f{0.9\\~}" at screen 0.25, 0.75 font ",20"
plot x
```

You get the following (wxt terminal):

[image]